# Xamarin Forms: Reference to type 'Assembly' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found

Tags: xamarin.forms

My Project type is Portable type. While deploying the project on UWP I'm getting the following error:

> Reference to type 'Assembly' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found.

The problem is only on the UWP part. Android and IOS apps are working fine.

The error occurs on the following line:

```
rendererAssemblies.AddRange(Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.GetExtraAssemblies());
Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, rendererAssemblies);
```

Tried to convert the Portable project type to .Net as per this [thread](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0VWCmj2adw). But It was throwing errors related to packages.

I'm still finding my way around Xamarin, any guidance to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: In version 3.0 Xamarin.Forms dropped support for Portable Class Libraries and is now targeting .NET Standard 2.0 only. This means the app must target at least Fall Creators Update (16299) in UWP to make sure it can be referenced.

Comment: My current app targets version is Windows 10, version 1903(10.0 Build 18362).

Comment: and did you change the  minimum version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this issue by updating `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` and installing `NSIS-Tool` packages under the windows project.